# MQTT - validation for incorrect IP and Port

Tags: java, mqtt

I want to validate that given IP and port are running in MQTT if not then i have to show exception to user. here is my code,

```
try {

                MqttMessage message2 = new MqttMessage();
                MQTT mqtt_connect = new MQTT();
                mqtt_connect.setHost(Host_Address, port);

                String topic = "/call/MQTT_Config";
                mqtt_connect.setClientId("MQTT_Config");
                mqtt_connect.setWillRetain(false);
                mqtt_connect.isWillRetain();
                mqtt_connect.setWillTopic(topic);
                BlockingConnection m_publisher = mqtt_connect.blockingConnection();

                m_publisher.connect();

                if(m_publisher.isConnected()){
                    System.out.println("connected");

                m_publisher.disconnect();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("not connected");
                    return "Port or IP may not running";
                }




            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failure";
            }
```

when i give correct IP and port then it goes to `if(m_publisher.isConnected())` condition fine but when i give wrong IP or port then it comes till `m_publisher.connect();` and then there is nothing happen, like loading console only.Is not going to next step. why?

i have to show some validation when user give unmatched IP or MQTT port. where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here will depend on what the user enters.

1. If they enter an IP address for a machine that exists but is not listening on the port then the machine will respond quickly with a connection refused message
2. If they enter an IP address for a machine that doesn't exist then the code will wait for the TCP timeout (default is 15mins) before raising an error.

Comment: ok i understand. so what is solution for this? is there any possible to set TCP timeout 1 min?